# Issues with mask multiple of the same identical mob in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

as discussed in the title I am having issues with masking identical images.

```
#initalising the masks
Invader1= pygame.image.load('Space_invaders_character_1_1.png').convert_alpha()

Invader1= pygame.transform.scale(Invader11, (40,30))

Invader1_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(Invader11)
Invader1_mask= Invader11_mask.scale((70,40))

Invader2= pygame.image.load('Space_invaders_character_2_1.png').convert_alpha()
Invader2= pygame.transform.scale(Invader21, (40,30))
Invader2_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(Invader21)
Invader2_mask= Invader11_mask.scale((70,40))
Invader3= pygame.image.load('Space_invaders_character_3_1.png').convert_alpha()
Invader3= pygame.transform.scale(Invader31, (40,30))
Invader3_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(Invader31)
Invader3_mask= Invader11_mask.scale((70,40))


#drawing characters
def drawEnemies (invX,invY):
    for num in range (1,11):
        invX = invX + 50
        gameDisplay.blit(Invader32, (invX,invY))
        gameDisplay.blit(Invader32, (invX,invY-50))
        gameDisplay.blit(Invader22, (invX,invY-100))
        gameDisplay.blit(Invader22, (invX,invY-150))
        gameDisplay.blit(Invader12, (invX, invY -200))
while lives > 0:
    offset = (bulletX -invX, bulletY - invY)
    result = Invader11_mask.overlap(bullet_mask, offset)
```

Of course this isn't all my code, however, I hope you see what I am attempting to do. In essence I am attempting to loop to create a specific Invader (yes from space invaders), however, the masks are either not being created with the other invaders or aren't moving. Can someone please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That would make it easier for us to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The meaningful answer to your problem is to stop what your doing right now and start using the [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) classes together with the [`collide_mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask) function.

You don't want to create several global variables for each thingy in your game. You want instances of classes (you usually use `Sprite`), and add them to a list (usually a `Group`).

So, create a class for your invaders that inherits from `Sprite` and give them a `mask` attribue, something like this:

```
class Invader(pygame.spriteSprite):
    def __init__(self, image, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(image)

    def update(self):
        pass # handle movement
```

Create a `Group` for your bullets and one for your invaders, then you can check the collision with:

```
pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, invaders, True, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
```